# Namespace prefixes in WCF SOAP Body (with Liquid XML Data Binding)

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

We are using the Liquid Data Binding library for a large set of object used in the WSDLs and XSDs for a SOAP service we use with WCF (for a receiveing and initiating services).  Everything is generally working without any problems.  We test our services (incoming and outgoing) through an online testing suite to gain a certification that we require for continues use of our endpoints with clients.

We pretty much pass all of our tests, except for one.  It is, technically, no any error or problem with the XML.  Instead it does not follow a best practices.

To illustrate our problem.  I will show the output we have now.  Followed by the desired output.  The difference is subtle, but important for us (which will be described at the end).

Current output:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        (truncated)
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <AdhocQueryRequest xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif" xmlns:rim="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0" xmlns:rs="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0" xmlns:query="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xdsb="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007" federated="false" startIndex="0" maxResults="-1">
            <query:ResponseOption returnType="LeafClass" returnComposedObjects="true"/>
            <rim:AdhocQuery id="urn:uuid:14d4debf-8f97-4251-9a74-a90016b0af0d" status="('urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:StatusType:Approved,urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:StatusType:Deprecated')">
                <rim:Slot name="$XDSDocumentEntryPatientId">
                    <rim:ValueList>
                        <rim:Value>
'RI0004.000000002^^^&2.16.840.1.113883.3.1259.10.1003&ISO'
                        </rim:Value>
                    </rim:ValueList>
                </rim:Slot>
                <rim:Slot name="$XDSDocumentEntryStatus">
                    <rim:ValueList>
                        <rim:Value>
('urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:StatusType:Approved,urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:StatusType:Deprecated')
                        </rim:Value>
                    </rim:ValueList>
                </rim:Slot>
            </rim:AdhocQuery>
        </AdhocQueryRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The desired output is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        (truncated)
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <query:AdhocQueryRequest xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif" xmlns:rim="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0" xmlns:rs="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0" xmlns:query="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xdsb="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007" federated="false" startIndex="0" maxResults="-1">
            <query:ResponseOption returnType="LeafClass" returnComposedObjects="true"/>
            <rim:AdhocQuery id="urn:uuid:14d4debf-8f97-4251-9a74-a90016b0af0d" status="('urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:StatusType:Approved,urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:StatusType:Deprecated')">
                <rim:Slot name="$XDSDocumentEntryPatientId">
                    <rim:ValueList>
                        <rim:Value>
'RI0004.000000002^^^&2.16.840.1.113883.3.1259.10.1003&ISO'
                        </rim:Value>
                    </rim:ValueList>
                </rim:Slot>
                <rim:Slot name="$XDSDocumentEntryStatus">
                    <rim:ValueList>
                        <rim:Value>
('urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:StatusType:Approved,urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:StatusType:Deprecated')
                        </rim:Value>
                    </rim:ValueList>
                </rim:Slot>
            </rim:AdhocQuery>
        </query:AdhocQueryRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The difference is the first child node under the SOAP Envelope Body, the AdhocQueryRequest node.  If the first example (our current output) the "urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:query:3.0" is repeated twice, once as a default (so the node, i guess doesn't need a prefix) and ANOTHER on defined for the "query" prefix (used in the further child nodes).  The standards committee reviewing our requests and responses for certification finds thee first form a non "best practice" (even though it is technically valid).

Now we had figured out a way to get the correct namespace prefixes in the output, which works for the child nodes.  However, we cannot figure out how to get rid of the node's default namespace and provide the "query" prefix in the AdHocQueryRequest node.  Does the "query" namespace need to be defined above it?  Is there something I am missing that will allow me to have the output like the second example?

Thanks

Comment: The namespace 'query' has to be defined in a parent node.  You do not have an xmlns in the xml with 'query' as the name.

Comment: That what I thought, in fact i just started going down that route.  Seeing if that works.  Thanks, though.